# Wordpress and Bootstrap- Unable to link scripts through functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Read the wordpress codex several times and I was still unable to link the files so that my dropdown menu could work. Is there anything I need to do that is not in the functions.php?

```
<?php
function load_js() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_js' );
?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're loading jQuery twice. Adding `array('jquery')` at the end makes sure jQuery is loaded *before* the scripts, and Wordpress does that automatically for you. You're enqueing your own version of jQuery, which depends on Wordpress' version of jQuery already being loaded. Remove the first `wp_enqueue_script` all together, it's not needed.

Comment: I removed the first wp_enqueue_script but it still didnt fix the problem

Comment: Then open the browser console (F12) and look for errors

Comment: Alternatively, with a simple fix using a local copy of jquery  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>